# Replace \r from json in shell

Tags: json, bash, shell, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

I have below **JSON** in a variable name `TASK_DEFINTIION`
It has a **\r** character at the end of `"image": "700707367057.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/php-demo:feature-feature01\r"` under **containerDefinitions**

I am using `TASK_DEFINITION_AFTER= 'echo $TASK_DEFINTIION | sed "s/\\r//g"'` to remove the **\r** but seems it is removing all the hidden carriage return but not removing the one which is visible as regular character.

Any help would be highly appriciated.

```
{
      "memory": "1024",
      "networkMode": "awsvpc",
      "family": "ecs-php-demo",
      "placementConstraints": [],
      "cpu": "512",
      "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::700707367057:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
      "volumes": [],
      "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
      ],
      "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::700707367057:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
      "containerDefinitions": [
        {
          "memoryReservation": 256,
          "environment": [],
          "name": "ecs-php-demo",
          "mountPoints": [],
          "image": "700707367057.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/php-demo:feature-feature01\r",
          "cpu": 0,
          "portMappings": [
            {
              "protocol": "tcp",
              "containerPort": 8080,
              "hostPort": 8080
            }
          ],
          "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
              "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
              "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs",
              "awslogs-group": "/ecs/ecs-php-demo"
            }
          },
          "essential": true,
          "volumesFrom": []
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: What produced the file? You should probably fix that so that it doesn't add the `\r` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command, first \ escapes the second \, so `sed` sees only one \

You need :

```
TASK_DEFINITION_AFTER="$(echo $TASK_DEFINTIION | sed "s/\\\\r//g")"
```

Comment: do you think its a good idea to parse json with `sed` or `awk` ?, the answer has to be changed with `jq`

Answer (score 2):

Using `jq` `rtrimstr` to stay conform with the JSON syntax:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

TASK_DEFINTIION="$(
  jq '.containerDefinitions[].image|=rtrimstr("\r")' <<<"$TASK_DEFINTIION"
)"

echo "$TASK_DEFINTIION"
```

`man jq`:

> **`rtrimstr(str)`**
>         Outputs its input with the given suffix string removed, if it ends with it.
>
> ```
>       jq ´[.[]|rtrimstr("foo")]´
>          ["fo", "foo", "barfoo", "foobar", "foob"]
>       => ["fo","","bar","foobar","foob"]
> ```

Comment: Why not just `TASK_DEFINITION=$(jq ... <<< "$TASK_DEFINITION")`?

Comment: You could also use `rtrimstr("\r")` instead of `gsub`. (I'm not sure I even understand how `gsub` is working: it clearly *does*, I just don't know *why*, given my understanding of `gsub`.)

Comment: @chepner I don't use the `=$(command)` assignment because it strips the trailing newline.

Comment: The JSON value won't end with any significant newlines.

Comment: @chepner I updated with your `rtrimstr` suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `jq` to replace key value:

```
jq '.containerDefinitions[].image="700707367057.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/php-demo:feature-feature01"' file.json
```

but unfortunately, `jq` does not support in-place editing, so you must redirect to a temporary file first and then replace your original file with it, or use `sponge` utility from the more utils package, like that:

```
jq '.containerDefinitions[].image="700707367057.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/php-demo:feature-feature01"' file.json|sponge file.json
```

A pure `jq` solution to remove `\r` with `gsub` :

```
jq '.containerDefinitions[].image|=gsub("[\r]"; "")' file.json|sponge file.json
```

output sample :

```
{
  "memory": "1024",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "family": "ecs-php-demo",
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "cpu": "512",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::700707367057:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "volumes": [],
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::700707367057:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "memoryReservation": 256,
      "environment": [],
      "name": "ecs-php-demo",
      "mountPoints": [],
      "image": "700707367057.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/php-demo:feature-feature01",
      "cpu": 0,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8080,
          "hostPort": 8080
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs",
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/ecs-php-demo"
        }
      },
      "essential": true,
      "volumesFrom": []
    }
  ]
}
```